# Can I create an audio source node from a fragment of an MP3 file?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'd like to create several source audio nodes each containing a different fragment of an MP3. Is there a way, having fetched the file, to create a source node from a given section of the file? At the moment I have:

```
var source1 = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

return fetch('speech.mp3')
  .then(function (response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
    }
    return response.arrayBuffer();
  })
  .then(function (buffer) {
    return audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer);
  })
  .then(function (decodedData) {
    source1.buffer = decodedData;
    source1.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  });
```

But I would like `source1` (and then a `source2` and `source3`) to contain different fragments of `speech.mp3`.

Comment: Do you mean different timeStart for each source?
Can you try {
    source1.buffer = decodedData;
    source2.buffer = decodedData;
....

    source2.currentTime = 10; }
?

Comment: @ArkadySpiridonov yes I mean a different start and end time for each source. The source nodes appear not to have a currentTime property.

Answer (score 0):

Since you read in all of "speech.mp3", you can create multiple `AudioBufferSourceNode` objects for various pieces of the mp3 file.  I can think of at least two ways.  Perhaps the easiest (untested):

```
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
  src[k] = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, decodedData);
  src[k].connect(context.destination);
  src[k].start(time[k], offset[k], duration[k]);
}
```

Each src uses the same AudioBuffer, but when you call `start()`, you specify the offset, `offset[k]`, and duration, `duration[k]`, from the decodedData that you want to play.

Alternatively, you can slice up the original `decodeData` into lots of smaller `AudioBuffer` objects containing the fragments you want to use.  Then each `AudioBufferSourceNode` can use that small buffer as its source.  This wastes space, though, to create all the little buffers.

Something like this (untested):

```
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
  // Grab the part of the mp3 that we want.
  d[k] = decodedData.slice(start[k], end[k]);
  b[k] = new AudioBuffer({length: d[k].length, sampleRate: context.sampleRate});
  b[k].copyToChannel(d[k], 0, 0);
  s[k] = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, {buffer: b[k]);
  // Play back this piece of the mp3 at the appropriate time.
  s[k].start(time[k]);
}
```

Comment: I'd tried the first approach but found the start times to be unreliable, with segments of audio sometimes starting far too early. Could you possibly expand the second approach?

Comment: If the segments start playing way too early, then you've scheduled them incorrectly. Or there's a bug in the implementation and you should file a bug with your implementation.  I'll update the answer with a more detail version for the second approach in a bit.